error en la libreria de whatsapp-web.js al intentar sacar la version y error con la libreria de puppeteer
Al intentar correr mi programa me sale este error de la libreria:
Bot\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:221
            throw new Error('Evaluation failed: ' + helper_js_1.helper.getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails));
                  ^

Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:5:95
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (.\Bot\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:221:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (.\Bot\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:110:16)
    at async Client.initialize (.\Bot\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\src\Client.js:323:9)

Si funcionaba en la mañana no movi nada y cuando me fije el programa habia crasheado y cuando inicio de nuevo me decia error.

Hola Ruben tenia el mismo problema, investigando encontre una solución
const client = new Client({
authStrategy: new LocalAuth({
    dataPath: "sessions",
}),
webVersionCache: {
    type: 'remote',
    remotePath: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wppconnect-team/wa-version/main/html/2.2412.54.html',
}});

Debes en tu cliente actualizar la línea de webVersionCache esto con el fin de solucionar el error, no se si sea una solución temporal o definitiva, pero me funciona por el momento

lo que dice Juan de momento funciona, te dejo un lugar donde puedes corroborarlo:
Saludos
https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/2965

A mí me funciono con la siguiente versión espero le ayude a alguien:
const wwebVersion = '2.2412.54'; 

this.client = new Client({
  authStrategy: new LocalAuth({
    clientId: "client-one"
  }),
  puppeteer: {
    args: ["--no-sandbox"],
  },
  webVersionCache: {
    type: 'remote',
    remotePath: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wppconnect-team/wa-version/main/html/${wwebVersion}.html`,
  },
});


Nuevamente tuve el mismo problema y encontré una muy buena solución por si a alguien le paso lo mismo que a mi les dejo el link:
npm install github:pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js#webpack-exodus
https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/pull/2816
